# How to make global variable in SvelteKit?

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I have a need to use global variables inside of

```html
<body tag data-svelteKit-preload-data="hover">
  <script type="module"> here </script>
</body>
```

in the `app.html` file in my SvelteKit application, but there is no way they want to be imported inside this file. Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm using the Facebook SDK, and it says that this code should be after opening the body tag

```html
<script type="module">
    import { env } from "@sveltejs/kit/env";
    
    const PRIVATE_KEY = useEnv();
            
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        myGlobalObject.FB = FB;
        FB.init({
            appId            : PUBLIC_KEY,
            autoLogAppEvents : true,
            xfbml            : true,
            version          : 'v18.0'
        });
    };
</script>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unsure what the problem is.  A global variable is a variable added to the global object.  In the browser, this is `window`.  Are you getting an error?  The most likely error you're getting is that "window is not defined".  Just use `globalThis.window` instead, if this is the case.

Comment: What I need to do if I need to use .env variable in app.html script? Its not work like in components (import { PUBLIC_KEY } from "$env/static/public";)?

Comment: You don't need to use .env, you're in the client, this code is accessible to all. You appId is not your app secret, you can simply hardcode it